# No such file or directory error in eclipse juno

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am currently working on a project in CDT(Eclipse Luno).I have some subdirectories under project. Like
1> dir1
....some source files and header files

2>dir2
....agains some source files and header files
3> so on some more directories

i added the path to all these directories into path variables via properties->
path and symbols 
but still when it encounters include directive like #include "dir1/someheaderfile".
 It does not recognise the file even when path has been added(In fact i added it to all the properties of all directories too).
I read other questions on stackoverflow and i ran index->rebuild still no change.please help.

Comment: You have added "c:\...\dir1" as directory? Have you tried #include "header.h" without dir1?

Comment: actually this is linux system . but your advice to try "header.h" without dir1 works! What is the reason for that?

Comment: Your paths specify the root-directory for searching. If you have pathvariable to dir1 and the #include "dir1/header.h" is like the path dir1/dir1/header.h.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of comments above:

include "header.h" without dir1

The paths specify the root-directory for searching. If you have pathvariable to dir1 and the #include "dir1/header.h" is like the path dir1/dir1/header.h.